# Check if user is logged in React Js

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys i have a JWT authentication in my react project i want to make a function to check if the user logged . My login function is like this :

```
export function login(data) {
    const endpoint = '/api/auth/jwt/'
    const csrfToken = cookie.load('csrftoken')
    let thisComp = this
    if (csrfToken !== undefined) {
      let lookupOptions = {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'

          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          credentials: 'include'
      }

      fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions)
      .then(function(response){
          return response.json()
      }).then(function(responseData){
          console.log(responseData)
          localStorage.token = responseData.token
          localStorage.expires = responseData.expires // Store the token
          console.log("Token Stored", localStorage.token)
          console.log("Token Expires", responseData.expires)

          refreshToken(data) // Put in to the refresh function


        }).catch(function(error){

          console.log("error", error)
      })
     }
}
```

and my function isLoggedIn is like this :

```
export function isLoggedIn() {
    // Check if we have a token stored 
    if (localStorage.token !== undefined) {
    // I also want to check if the token is still work and don't expire 
    // i have acces to the expiration date like this :
    // localStorage.token == > Token Expires 2018-06-19T14:51:59.451703Z in 
    the console 
    // How can check if the token still work ? 
    return true
    }
    return false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just check the expires property you stored in your local storage and compare it to current Date ?

Other ways to handle it: store the expiration date in the token itself, then use a jwt decoding library to decode the token and extract it from there. If you are using refresh tokens you can simply wait for the server to return a 401 Unauthorized response and send the refresh token to request a new one.